# Neo4j: Creating multiple relationships between two nodes without redundancy

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create 2 (or more) relationships with 2 nodes. I am using this code:

```
match (b:Base{name:"Base 1"})
create (b)-[:Negative]->(nakereba:Addon{name:"nakereba"}), (b)-[r2:Conditional]->(nakereba)
```

I would like to write something short, like this:

```
create (b)-[:Negative:Conditional]->(:Addon{name:"nakereba"})
```

Answer (score 0):

A neo4j relationship has one and only one type, so I am afraid it is not possible to collapse the 2 relationships (with different types) into one.

Comment: It doesn't have to be exactly `[:A:B]`.